# MySQL Compare a String Ignoring Non-Alphanumeric Characters

Tags: php, mysql, regex, url, comparison

I am trying to query the database using the URL passed in as a query string to find the correct article, for example:

```
http://localhost/article/articles-name-here
```

Normally in the database the article's name would look as such: 'article's name here' so if I try to find it as it appears in the URL without the quote `'` then I get an error.

Is this the proper way of achieving such a result like Stackoverflow does with question names in the URL? If this is the way then how would I be able to ignore all non-alphanumeric characters in the MySQL search? Thanks!

Comment: FYI you'll notice stackoverflow also has an ID in the url (`22802443` for your question). Its URLs work with only the ID, but not with only the slugged text.

Comment: Great! I was skeptical about using the full URL because comparison is much slower and problematic so the name of the question is mostly SEO purposed I see. Thank you Robin!